# Hide Properly Download Button

Tags: html

I have an audio playing site and I want to prevent the users from downloading the sounds 
from the HTML audio element download button. So I wrote:

```
<audio src="sound.mp3" controls controlsList="nodownload"></audio>
```

It works fine but I can delete the controlsList="nodownload" from inspect element and then 
the download-button appears.

Any ideas of how to deal with it?

Comment: You can’t prevent users from doing that.

Comment: This answer sounds very condescending. Anything I could try to stop the average user from downloading?

Comment: If stopping the "average user" is what you are after `nodownload` is perfect. In my experience, the average user is not someone who uses browser developer tools.

Comment: Can I do something with css? or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop a user from downloading a file if you give him access to. When the user is reading the audio file on his computer, the computer is actually downloading the file in his RAM while playing it. Nothing can prevent the user from simply storing this data in his hard-drive.

The only way to stop the user from being able to download the file is by not letting him play it.

You can use [DRM-wrapped content on the web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions). Here is a [list of the web browsers supporting DRM content](https://drmtoday.com/faq/#html5drm).

Answer (score 0):

Everything you hear or you see on your browser is downloaded from different sources. How browser can write some text or play music if its protected by server/by you? Even if browser protect all these things from you for example if theres no way to download Rihannas new song from SoundCloud, you can allways record it. Sorry, but you can do nothing about that.